# Viewing maps with PyQt4 QWebView using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, openstreetmap

I am building a program that can show a map with a markers according to specific coordinates from a database, so the process is:

1. Get the map from osm using (folium)
2. Add the marker
3. Save the map as HTML
4. Show the map.html in QWebView.

But this way is not practical if the coordinates are always changing e.g(vehicles tracking system).

Is there anyway that could allow me to add or update markers on the map avoiding the previous process, without having to create the map.html file then load it to QWebView then showing it every time .

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some time ago I had created a small library to show markers in maps using PyQt and [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps) or [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/), because of your question I added this functionality so you can download the code from this [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/qMap) and try the example: qOSMExample2.py

In this answer I'll show you the most important parts of my code so that you can add custom functionality.

QWebView supports javascript so I used the leaflet library, and this is included in the html as shown below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>


    <style type="text/css">
   html { height: 100%; }
   body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
   #mapid { height: 100% }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-07I2e+7D8p6he1SIM+1twR5TIrhUQn9+I6yjqD53JQjFiMf8EtC93ty0/5vJTZGF8aAocvHYNEDJajGdNx1IsQ=="
          crossorigin=""/>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-A7vV8IFfih/D732iSSKi20u/ooOfj/AGehOKq0f4vLT1Zr2Y+RX7C+w8A1gaSasGtRUZpF/NZgzSAu4/Gc41Lg=="
            crossorigin=""></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="qOSM.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="mapid" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In addition if we observe I have imported the **qOSM.js** file that implements the logic of creating, moving the map and the same with the markers.

The other important is to interact python with javascript for it pyqt offers us 2 functions:

> **void QWebFrame::addToJavaScriptWindowObject(const QString & name, QObject * object)**
>
> Make object available under name from within the frame's JavaScript
>   context. The object will be inserted as a child of the frame's window
>   object.
>   [...]

```
self.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("qtWidget", self)
```

> **QVariant QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript(const QString & scriptSource)**
>
> Evaluates the JavaScript defined by scriptSource using this frame as
>   context and returns the result of the last executed statement.

```
def runScript(self, script):
    return self.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(script)
```

The first function allows us to embed a python object in js and so we can output signals from js and connect them to python slots. The second is oriented to execute functions of js and receive what returns. In summary the first one serves to obtain answers asynchronously and the second one synchronously.

In the next part I show the js where the functions mentioned above are implemented:

```js
// Where you want to render the map.

var map;

var markers = [];

var LeafIcon;

function initialize() {
    var element = document.getElementById('mapid');

    map = L.map(element);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    if (typeof qtWidget !== 'undefined') {

        map.on('dragend', function () {
            center = map.getCenter();
            qtWidget.mapMoved(center.lat, center.lng);
        });

        map.on('click', function (ev) {
            qtWidget.mapClicked(ev.latlng.lat, ev.latlng.lng);
        });

        map.on('dblclick', function (ev) {
            qtWidget.mapDoubleClicked(ev.latlng.lat, ev.latlng.lng);
        });

        map.on('contextmenu', function (ev) {
            qtWidget.mapRightClicked(ev.latlng.lat, ev.latlng.lng);
        });
    }

    LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [38, 95],
            shadowSize: [50, 64],
            iconAnchor: [22, 94],
            shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
            popupAnchor: [-3, -76]
        }
    });
}

function osm_setCenter(lat, lng) {
    //console.log(lat);
    map.panTo(new L.LatLng(lat, lng));
}

function osm_getCenter() {
    return map.getCenter();
}

function osm_setZoom(zoom) {
    map.setZoom(zoom);
}

function osm_addMarker(key, latitude, longitude, parameters) {

    if (key in markers) {
        osm_deleteMarker(key);
    }

    if ("icon" in parameters) {

        parameters["icon"] = new L.Icon({
            iconUrl: parameters["icon"],
            iconAnchor: new L.Point(16, 16)
        });
    }

    var marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude], parameters).addTo(map);

    if (typeof qtWidget !== 'undefined') {

        marker.on('dragend', function (event) {
            var marker = event.target;
            qtWidget.markerMoved(key, marker.getLatLng().lat, marker.getLatLng().lng);
        });

        marker.on('click', function (event) {
            var marker = event.target;
            //marker.bindPopup(parameters["title"]);
            qtWidget.markerClicked(key, marker.getLatLng().lat, marker.getLatLng().lng);
        });

        marker.on('dbclick', function (event) {
            var marker = event.target;
            qtWidget.markerClicked(key, marker.getLatLng().lat, marker.getLatLng().lng);
        });

        marker.on('contextmenu', function (event) {
            var marker = event.target;
            qtWidget.markerRightClicked(key, marker.getLatLng().lat, marker.getLatLng().lng);
        });
    }

    markers[key] = marker;
    return key;
}

function osm_deleteMarker(key) {
    map.removeLayer(markers[key]);
    delete markers[key];
}

function osm_moveMarker(key, latitude, longitude) {
    marker = markers[key];
    var newLatLng = new L.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    marker.setLatLng(newLatLng);
}

function osm_posMarker(key) {
    marker = markers[key];
    return [marker.getLatLng().lat, marker.getLatLng().lng];
}


http://
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, this is exactly what i was looking for :).  I did a little modifications to your library and it worked for me.

Comment: @ eyllanesc I downloaded your code from github but I get the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKit'`. Except `PyQt5` and `qgmap`, should I install another library? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @H.Dave What version of PyQt5 do you have? What example have you executed?

Comment: @ eyllanesc I have `PyQt5==5.9.1` version and I tried `qGmapExample`

Comment: @H.Dave I will upgrade from QWebEngineView, but before that tell me if you can execute the following command: `from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView`

Comment: @H.Dave Okay, I'm going to update my library these days.

Comment: @ eyllanesc Thank you very much !!

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, I couldn't find the example file on the repo https://github.com/eyllanesc/qMap, is it still working?